# QGIS 3 and Python import qgis.core error

Tags: qgis, python, gdal, error, osgeo

I am trying to set up QGIS3 and python so I can write a script that uses GDAL- I want to do this from the OSGEO4W shell. I have read a lot of questions and followed some tutorials which led me to do this once installing the software:

Firstly I load this cmd which works without error in the OSGEO4W shell:

```
@echo off
SET OSGEO4W_ROOT=C:\OSGeo4W64 
call "%OSGEO4W_ROOT%"\bin\o4w_env.bat

@echo off
path %PATH%;%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qgis\bin
path %PATH%;%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\Qt5\bin
path %PATH%;%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\Python36\Scripts

set PYTHONPATH=%PYTHONPATH%;%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qgis\python
set PYTHONHOME=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\Python36
set PATH=C:\Users\Issy\Documents\QGIS;%PATH%
```

Then there is the issue:

```
python3

Python 3.6.0 (v3.6.0:41df79263a11, Dec 23 2016, 08:06:12) [MSC v.1900 64 bit 
(AMD64)] on win32

import qgis.core

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\qgis\python\qgis\core\__init__.py", line 27, in ><module>
    from qgis._core import *
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.
```

I have tried numerous `pythonpath` settings and installed/re-installed with different settings but I just can't get this to work.

Comment: There is a template for a batch file to call python from the osgeo4w shell in bin. Rename it by removing the tmpl-extension. Also, to use gdal, you don't need the qgis module, just import gdal.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem stated above. I want use not only GDAL but QGIS. This is the content of my .bat file (located in C:\OSGeo4W64):

```
**@echo off

SET OSGEO4W_ROOT=C:\OSGeo4W64

call "%OSGEO4W_ROOT%"\bin\o4w_env.bat

call "%OSGEO4W_ROOT%"\apps\grass\grass-7.4.1\etc\env.bat

path %PATH%;%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qgis\bin

path %PATH%;%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\grass\grass-7.4.1\lib

path %PATH%;C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\Qt5\bin

path %PATH%;C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\Python37\Scripts

set PYTHONPATH=%PYTHONPATH%;%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qgis\python

set PYTHONHOME=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\Python37

set PATH=C:\Program Files\Git\bin;%PATH%

cmd.exe**
```

Firstly, it worked on one computer but on **the other** not (both Windows 10):
[image]

Difference: during installation (**the other**)
[image]

I:

1. Uninstall OSGeo4W64
2. Chceck Windows updates
3. Uninstall old versions of Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable Package
4. Install: Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable Package (x64)
5. Install: Windows 10 Universal C Runtime
6. Install OSGeo4W64 (advanced install>>check:

[image]

and next window chceck to install the rest of recommended packages.

It works. Maybe it'll help somebody.